# Range.map no longer working in Google Apps Script for Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a custom function in Google Sheets that used Range.map to check if the parameter was a multi-cell range vs a single value (or single cell range). I wrote it over a year ago and hadn't been back to this function in a while, but I noticed today it does not work. the rangeVariable.map returns undefined, as does rangeVariable.length.

I can't find documentation on what to replace these with if they're no longer working, or even if they're confirmed to no longer work

```
function FormattedEmail(DisplayName, Email, Separator) {
  var sep = Separator == null ? ',' : Separator;
  if (DisplayName.map && Email.map) {     //Both DisplayName and Email are ranges
    if (DisplayName.length != Email.length) {  //DisplayName and Email ranges must match
```

Updated to include information from TheMaster:

> Ranges passed as parameters to custom functions should be passed as Arrays, so any array methods should work, including .map. However the variable does not seem to be an Array, but an object.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments

Comment: There is no `.map` function on  class `range`. Never was.

Comment: @TheMaster I think the OP confuses vba with google apps script. But I am not sure why his code was "working" before and now it is not..

Comment: I assure you I did not confuse vba with Google Apps script. .map returned true for multicell ranges I believe because they were treated as arrays. It seems that that is not currently the case.

Comment: If there is a range.map function could you please share the relevant official documentation? If there is none, then it means that this method does not exist. The only thing close to your question would be: `getRange(..).getValues().map(..)`

Comment: The documentation does not exist, but it used to work. It was how I checked if the untyped parameter was a range in the custom function. I'll admit I shouldn't have been using an undocumented way to check if a variable was a range, but I did and it worked even if you don't believe that. My problem now is I don't know how to check if a variable is a Range

Comment: Check `console.log(typeof  value)` it will return `range` if `value` is a range object. Can you confirm which environment are you using ? Rhino or v8 ? It might be that Rhino had some strange declarations.

Comment: In a custom function, ranges were never passed. Only the range's values were passed as array.

Comment: Anyway, to close this discussion. It is always recommended in any programming language to use the official documentation and the best practices. Now we are trying to prove that what you are saying never existed. But instead you should be looking for a solution that does exist.

Comment: To quote the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments), ``If you call your function with a reference to a range of cells as an argument (like =DOUBLE(A1:B10)), the argument will be a two-dimensional array of the cells' values.``

Comment: Reading the documentation it seems that a range's values being passed as an array is still what happens. So .map should work and yet it doesn't. FWIW typeof returns "object"

Comment: Array is also a type of ``object``(`console.log(typeof ([]))`). I think Diego's answer should help.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show how the function is being called.

Comment: To expand on TheMaster's comment a little - arrays are ["exotic objects"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-exotic-object-internal-methods-and-slots) (i.e. roughly extensions of `Object`) just as `Date`s are. Also worth noting that it is never a good idea to test for types by presence of a method/property, you should use the existing type guard system (`typeof`, `instanceof`, `Number.isNaN`, `Array.isArray`).

Answer (score 1):

A custom function doesn't really take a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). It's best explained in the [arguments documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments)

> If you call your function with a reference to a range of cells as an argument (like =DOUBLE(A1:B10)), the argument will be a two-dimensional array of the cells' values. For example, in the screenshot below, the arguments in =DOUBLE(A1:B2) are interpreted by Apps Script as double([[1,3],[2,4]]). Note that the sample code for DOUBLE from above would need to be modified to accept an array as input.
>
> [image]

What's less obvious is that passing in a single cell reference will not be interpreted as an array, but as a single value. Try this:

```
// =isArray(B4) == false
// =isArray(B4:B5) == true

function isArray(arg) {
  if (arg.map) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

So, in your custom function, if either `DisplayName` or `Email` are *not* arrays, you won't get past that first if statement. That is likely the reason why the function isn't working for you: one or more of your inputs is invalid. You should be able to resolve that in your function.

I assume that by calling `DisplayName.map`, you're actually trying to check if `DisplayName` is an array. This works because calling `map` on an object without that method (like a string), will return `undefined`. But it's probably better to be more explicit and use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```
function FormattedEmail(DisplayName, Email, Separator) {
  var sep = Separator == null ? ',' : Separator;
  if (Array.isArray(DisplayName) && Array.isArray(Email)) {
    if (DisplayName.length != Email.length) {
```

Comment: I don't think it's  "less obvious", the previous statement in documentation says exactly that: `If you call your function with a reference to a single cell as an argument (like =DOUBLE(A1)), the argument will be the value of the cell.`

Comment: @TheMaster I was trying to highlight that it's not an array, but you're right.